# How to send http requests and errors to New Relic Network section

Tags: java, android, http, newrelic

I need to send some URLs to Network section on New Relic.

For success case it has to be shown at HTTP requests section, and for failed case it has to be shown at HTTP errors section.

Any idea what how I can send some URL to those 2 sections, is there any method for these 2 sections?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can populate the data in the Mobile > Network > HTTPRequest/HTTPErrors from the [Notice HTTP Transaction](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/android-sdk-api/notice-http-transaction/) and [Notice Network Failure](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/android-sdk-api/notice-network-failure/) using these Agent SDK methods metrics gathered here will appear in the UI indicted above.